# Customizing Google Trivia or Personality Quiz

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am wanting to create a simple Action for Google Assistant that will ask a series of yes/no personality type questions, then interpret the result at the end. (eg. Based on your answers you are assertive / not very assertive)

For each question it needs to know whether "yes" implies trait A (eg. assertive) or trait B (eg. not assertive).

I cannot use the Trivia template because it insists on giving the "right" answer to each question as soon as it is answered, and there is no "right" answer.

I don't think I can use the Personality template because it insistes on a Trait being entered for each question and it only asks one question for each trait. I want to ask all of the questions.

Is it possible to use one of those templates initially, then modify it afterwards somehow to do what I want, or do I have to build the project from scratch in Dialogflow or JavaScript for example?

Comment: if the user is giving answer in just yes/no, then why do you need dialogflow for?

Comment: It needs to know for each question whether Yes implies A or B and it needs to keep a count of the total for A and the total for B then at the end it needs to interpret the results.